# What is the fear of having regrets called?

Tags: fear, phobia

What is the clinical name of fear of regrets? I'm thinking of something like arachnophobia or something ending with the prefix "-phobia"

could it be something like apóleiafovía? (the literal greek translation of fear of loss)

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  What makes you think that this is a "thing" - ie, something that actually happens, and therefore deserves a clinical term?  There are very long lists of phobias easily found through your favorite search engine, but none of them that I can see mention this one.  There are fears of ridicule, being laughed at, making decisions, responsibility, failure, but not regrets, guilt, or disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a clinical diagnosis, in research on social media the term **"Fear of Missing Out" (FoMo)** is often used [(Przybylski et al., 2013)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chb.2013.02.014):

> Defined as a pervasive apprehension that others might be having rewarding experiences from which one is absent, FoMO is characterized by the desire to stay continually connected with what others are doing.

This sounds related, but perhaps more specific in that it focuses specifically on regret of not having experienced a rewarding experience online.

Przybylski, A. K., Murayama, K., DeHaan, C. R., & Gladwell, V. (2013). [Motivational, emotional, and behavioral correlates of fear of missing out.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chb.2013.02.014) Computers in human behavior, 29(4), 1841-1848.

Answer (score -2):

Arachnophobia = fear of spiders.
Neuroticism = condition to feer loss (but I won't diagnose conditions as I am not certified for this).
Atychiphobia = fear of failure